# PHP MySQL Codeigniter Restful API - Return of danish letters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rest

I have this Application where I use Codeigniter as backend and BackboneJS as frontend. I use the RESTful API to display data from the DB on the frontend. Even though, my API doesnt return danish letters, for example:

```
public function ø_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM `artists` WHERE formated_name LIKE 'Ø%'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

    if($data) {
        $this->response($data, 200); 
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter ø!'), 404);
    }
}
```

In my network tab it says `%C3%B8`- not found!

How can I solve this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things - do not use special chars in your function names... it is bad practice. Furthermore the codepage on your webpage and in your database needs to be identical. Set for example both to `utf-8`

Comment: yep, dont use special chars in functions, but if you strongly need this: go on to `/application/config/config.php` to experiment with permitted_uri_chars list